# How to calculate the carrying capacity from relative growth rate?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following table of data recording the millions of cell phone subscriptions in the United States in any given year between $1985$ and $2008:$

[image]

Let $s(t)$ be the number of cell phone subscriptions at time $t$, measured in years since $1989.$

I am to answer the following $6$ questions, of which I only need help with part (f), but will include all for context:

> (a) Estimate the relative growth rate of $s(t)$ at $t = 1.$ That is, estimate the relative rate for the year $1990$. Express this growth rate as a percentage. [Hint: The best estimate involves the number of cell phones at $1989$ and $1991.$]
>
> (b) In general, if a quantity grows exponentially, how does its relative growth rate change?
>
> (c) Also estimate the relative growth rates of $s(t)$ for the years $1991–2007.$
>
> (d) How long after $1989$ was the number of subscriptions growing exponentially?
>
> (e) In general, if a quantity grows according to a logistic model, how does its relative growth rate change?
>
> (f) Using your results in part (c), calculate the carrying capacity for this model. [Hint: There is more than one way to do this calculation.]

$$$$

Since I only need help with part (f), I will reproduce my answer to part (c) here since it is used in part (f).

In part (c), we are asked to 'estimate' the relative growth rates for the years $1991-2007.$ According to part (a), it appears the best estimate for the growth rate for any given year is subtracting the preceding year's subscriptions from the succeeding year's subscriptions, and averaging the results.

Thus we use the following formula to estimate the growth rate for any given year between $1991$ and $2007$:

$$\frac{ds}{dt}\bigg|_{t_i}=\frac{s(t_{i+1})-s(t_{i-1})}{t_{i+1}-t_{i-1}}$$

where the notation $t_i$ for any $i\in\{1991, 1992, ..., 2007\}$ means evaluation at $i$ or in other words $t_i=i$.

We obtain the following data: \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Year& s(t) & \frac{ds}{dt} & \frac{1}{s(t)} \frac{ds}{dt} \\ \hline
1990&5.3 \times 10^6 & 2.05\times 10^6 &0.390\\ \hline
1991& 7.6\times 10^6& 2.85\times 10^6 &0.375\\ \hline
1992&11\times 10^6 &4.20 \times 10^6 &0.382\\ \hline
1993& 16\times 10^6&6.50 \times 10^6 &0.406\\ \hline
1994&24\times 10^6 &9.00 \times 10^6 &0.375\\ \hline
1995& 34\times 10^6&10.00 \times 10^6 &0.294\\ \hline
1996& 44\times 10^6&10.50 \times 10^6 &0.239\\ \hline
1997& 55\times 10^6&12.50\times 10^6 &0.227\\ \hline
1998&69\times 10^6 &15.50\times 10^6 &0.225\\ \hline
1999& 86\times 10^6&20.50 \times 10^6 &0.238\\ \hline
2000& 110\times 10^6&21.00\times 10^6 &0.191\\ \hline
2001&128\times 10^6 &15.50\times 10^6 &0.121\\ \hline
2002& 141\times 10^6&15.50\times 10^6 &0.110\\ \hline
2003& 159\times 10^6&20.50\times 10^6 &0.129\\ \hline
2004&182\times 10^6 &24.50\times 10^6 &0.135\\ \hline
2005& 208\times 10^6&25.50\times 10^6 &0.123\\ \hline
2006&233\times 10^6 &21.00\times 10^6 &0.090\\ \hline
2007&250\times 10^6 &15.00\times 10^6 &0.060\\ \hline
2008& 263\times 10^6& &\\ \hline
\end{array}

$$$$

For part (f), we are told to calculate the carrying capacity of this model. I am unsure of how to proceed that doesn't involve using statistical methods, which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is
$$
\frac{ds}{dt}=rs\left(1-\frac{s}{N}\right)
$$
for logistic growth with a maximal capacity of $N$. Thus the computed quantity $\frac1s\frac{ds}{dt}$ is assumed to be a linear function of $s$ that has its root at the carrying capacity. Thus do a linear regression for the data $(s,\frac1s\frac{ds}{dt})$ to find the estimate for $N$.